# tfidf oucomes are different for the exact same word

Tags: python, pandas, gensim, tf-idf, corpus

I'm running tfidf model in python.

```
texts=[**tokenized words**]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = list(map(dictionary.doc2bow,texts))
test_model = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf = test_model[corpus]
```

And it returns the output which gives some patterns of values to the exact same word.
For example, I chose the word "AAA".

```
         key          score
0       "AAA"       1
2323    "AAA"       0.896502
4086    "AAA"       0.844922
```

Why do they have every different value even though they are exact same.

Answer (score 1):

TFIDF stands for Term Frequency inverse document frequency. This means that for every token in each document a TFIDF vectorisation will first count the frequency of the token in the document. Then it will inversely weight the token frequency by the proportion of documents that also have the token in them.

The result is that every token in each document will have a value that reflects its significance to *that particular document*, negatively weighted by its presence across all documents.

Some TFIDF processors may also add an extra dimension of weighting based on how many other tokens are in each document.

In short the same token has different scores in different documents because that token probably occurs more prevalently in some documents than others. This prevalence is either due to it being more frequent, or by accounting for a larger proportion of the document's tokens.